# Where's table info tab on MySQL Workbench EER?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, diagram

When I select a table on EER Diagram on MySQL Workbench, the first tab shown is "Columns" instead of "Table" information where I can add comments to the table, change the engine, etc. Where's the "Table" tab?

[image]

I've seen this print screen from another user and it's clearly that a "Table" tab exists:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when you don't know an application, and you think you should be able to do something, it takes a little bit of playing around. That is what I did.

Observe the two arrows on the right hand side from one picture to the other!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It was so obvious! Hahaha. Thank you!